# Jasmine: Jodit is not defined, Unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, jodit

I'm trying to test our customized Jodit editor in app but even automatic 'should create' test is failed. Failure message is 'Jodit is not defined'.

*jodit.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, } from '@angular/core';

declare var Jodit: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jodit',
  templateUrl: './jodit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jodit.component.css']
})

export class JoditComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() ... ;
  @Output() ... ;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.editor = new Jodit('#' + this.elementId, ...
      });
```

*jodit.component.spec.ts*

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { JoditComponent } from './jodit.component';

describe('JoditComponent', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<JoditComponent>;
  let component: JoditComponent;


  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ JoditComponent ]
    })

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JoditComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }); 
});
```

I'm really new in Angular and testing at all but i'm wondering may be i've declared Jodit variable false or someting from imports is missed. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.spec.ts` file, you have to `import` Jodit and bundle it the same way you have in your `jodit.component.ts`. Maybe the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` needs it as well.

[Add a typescript library to angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949457/add-a-typescript-library-to-angular)

Check that out but in your tests you have to import it as well.

I would use the Angular wrapper though if I were you: https://github.com/jodit/jodit-angular

Comment: I've used wrapper but there is still same error shown. I've also added 
import { JoditAngularModule } from 'jodit-angular'; and imports: [JoditAngularModule], to my spec file. What do you mean by bundling Jodit? btw error is caused at JoditComponent.ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Once you do `imports: [JoditAngularModule]` in both your `module` and `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, you don't need `new Jodit`. You use it like `<jodit-editor>`.

Comment: Ok, i got it now :) But if i want to use case without wrapper, what should i do then? Which import exactly is missed?

Comment: I am not sure, how did you include the stuff in your component without the wrapper? You have to do it in a similar way.